# I was fiddling with aircrack-ng, trying to learn it mistakenly killing wpa_suplicant process

Tags: 20.04, aircrack-ng

I now have no Wifi interface in my settings. When I got to the Wifi settings, I only get the Airplane mode option. I tried restarting `wpa_suplicant` in the terminal, but I fear my lack of knowledge may cause further damages. How do I properly restart `wpa_supplicant`?

The steps I did were `Airmon-ng start wlan0` then it found several processes that could interfere and I blindly typed `airmon-ng check kill` which resulted in killing the `wpa_supplicant` process.

Answer (score 0):

To those who had similar problems to mine, you can fix it by starting NetworkManager again via the terminal command `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start`.